# Framing bytes (Begining and End) to be added inside the TCP/IP protocol on the client request

Tags: c#, .net, tcp

I am writing `TCP/IP` Client using C# - `System.Net.Sockets` to call the Interface created in the TCP/IP Socket on the **'X'** Server.

> Message body text format - 20 digits(ASCII format)

All messages text will be framed with below format,

> Framing bytes - 2 digit Hexadecimal values
>
> - Needs to be add in the starting and ending fields
> - It needs to be in the TCP/IP protocol and not within the body of the message.

**Question:** How do I add hexadecimal framing bytes in the TCP/IP protocol and not within the body of message.

Here is my code snippet -

```
           public static void Connect()
           {
                // Create a TcpClient.
                // Note, for this client to work you need to have a TcpServer 
                // connected to the same address as specified by the server, port
                // combination.
                Int32 port = 1234;
                String server = "serverip";
                String message = "12345678901234567890"
                TcpClient client = new TcpClient(server, port);

                // Translate the passed message into ASCII and store it as a Byte array.
                Byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);

                // Get a client stream for reading and writing.
                //  Stream stream = client.GetStream();

                NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

                // Send the message to the connected TcpServer. 
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

                Console.WriteLine("Sent: {0}", message);

                // Receive the TcpServer.response.

                // Buffer to store the response bytes.
                data = new Byte[256];

                // String to store the response ASCII representation.
                String responseData = String.Empty;

                // Read the first batch of the TcpServer response bytes.
                Int32 bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);
                Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", responseData);

                // Close everything.
                stream.Close();
                client.Close();
            
            Console.WriteLine("\n Press Enter to continue...");
            Console.Read();
        }
```

Comment: Bytes are bytes. That's it. Hexadecimal is a representation of the value of the byte(s).

Comment: _"It needs to be in the TCP/IP protocol and not within the body of the message"_ -- you will need to be more specific. Your description makes it sound like you are dealing with a protocol that is for some reason requiring that you operate at the raw socket layer, rather than the application layer. If you need clarification on the specification itself, Stack Overflow is the wrong place to seek that; you need to go to the author of the spec. If you yourself understand the specification and need help implementing it, you can get that help here, but you need to be more specific about the spec.

Answer (score 0):

Framing bytes (you dont say what they contain, it looks like you are quoting from a spec) seem to be needed to be added before and after the message, just send them. Assumed that the before bytes are 0x1234

```
var pre = new Byte[2];
pre[0] = 0x12;
pre[1] = 0x34;
stream.Write(pre, 0, 2);
```

then after the body of the message send the trailer the same way

Comment: What part of this answer addresses the need for the bytes to be _"in the TCP/IP protocol and not within the body of the message"_? This answer does not appear to be useful.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I ignored that ' requirement' since its almost certinalu a misunderstanding , you pointed this out yourself

Comment: _"you pointed this out yourself"_ -- I never suggested it must be a misunderstanding. It _could_ be, but it just as easily could be a correct understanding, depending on what the remote host requires. For example, certain domain-specific industrial hardware might use an oddball TCP/IP protocol where the client is expected to operate at the raw sockets level. Unless this is clarified in the question, no useful answer can be provided.